# What's the easiest way in Xcode to search exclusively for all writes to (or reads from) a variable

Tags: xcode, search

I find myself doing this from time to time and I end up just doing a search on the variable name and then looking through all the hits, skipping the ones that aren't what I'm looking for. But it occurred to me that if Xcode could reliably filter into one set or the other, it would make the process more efficient. Because quite often one only needs to know where a variable is changed in particular, so reads don't really matter then.

I can think of some ways eg. searching for "setXXX" and "XXX =" etc. but that all seems a bit clunky and imprecise. Is there a better way?

I am mostly coding in Objective-C and am looking for a way to do a static search of the source code.

Comment: Can you better clarify what you want to achieve? Are you talking about static analysis of your code, runtime execution or logs?

Comment: @jvarela Usually I find myself doing this in order to understand the lifecycle of a variable and/or to debug issues that arise when a variable has a value other than that which is expected

Comment: Yes, I understood that part. :) But what I want to know if you want a way to search that in your source code, or at run time using the debugger or in a text file that you generate concerning the execution of your program. I assume the first case, but I need to know in order to help you. Moreover, you don't specify the programming language you are using. I think you should edit your question with those details.

Comment: ok. question updated

Answer (score 1):

What I do when I want to search for a symbol in Xcode I use the built-in search tool as you suggested in your question and that is good enough for me. However, if you want better tools for static analysis of obj-c code I'd suggest XClarify from CodeGears. It became free for open source contributors and research.